# When it comes to applicability, how is "const int &i" different from "const int i" if they're both initialized with a literal/expression?

Tags: c++, reference, initialization, constants

I'm still quite new to C++, but to me so far, there seems to be no difference between the two when it comes to applicability. The only difference that I'm aware of is that reference to const objects is bound to a temporary object whenever initialized with a literal or an expression.

But since the temporary exists as long as the reference that's bound to it exists, there seems to be no applicable differences between a reference to const and a const variable if they're both initialized by a literal/expression.

So is there any situation where you can only, or would rather, choose one over the other?

Comment: I don't think for `int` it will make a difference or any intrinsic type. But start using classes, particularly when things like resources and user-managed memory are involved, and it can start to make a difference (eg code like `function ( Object(1,2,3) );`).

Comment: Reference to const is bound directly if the expression being bound is of the same type as the reference (or a derived type)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no difference.
Imagine that reference is "another name for constant or variable".

Comment: Do you know why this functionality was ever implemented? Was it for the sake of consistency among other related kinds of functionality, or just some coincidence from the way the underlying system was designed?

Comment: It was some coincidence. `const int &i = j` - `i` is another name for `j`. `const int &i = 4` - `i` is a name for unnamed area where `4` is located. And this is similar with `const int i = 4` - declaration of area named `i` which consists value `4`.

Comment: This answer isn't really correct, the op is mistaken in his assertion that the temporary always lasts as long as the reference, as noted by msalters.

Answer (score 3):

At function scope, there's no difference. The temporary bound to the reference will exist until the function returns.

However, for class members the reference will still be destroyed when the relevant function returns, and that relevant function is the *constructor* - not the *destructor*! The constructor does the initialization and therefore the temporary exists only in the constructor.

Things of course work correctly if you have a `const int` member.

Answer (score 2):

`const int &i` means that `i` refers to another `int`, which cannot be modified *through this reference*. However that int could be modified elsewhere.

For example:

```
int j = 5;
const int &i = j;
const int k = 5;

cout << i << "," << k << endl;   // same

j = 6;

cout << i << "," << k << endl;   // different
```

You're right that the cast `const int &i = 5;` is very similar to `const int i = 5;`. However for class types the similarity fades.